# Exporting CocoaLumberjack logs with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

In one of my apps in the past I was able to allow users to export CocoaLumberjack logs from the device, using `UIActivityViewController`, passing in an array of file URLs pointing to the logs on the user's device.

However even though I (think I) have ported over the same code from my older app, I cannot get any options to show in UIActivityViewController either on a device or the simulator. All I get is "more":

[image: Empty UIActivityViewController]

In my other app I get options to share to Slack, Mail, Files, etc like most other files.

To try and understand what I'm doing wrong I created a sample project but I'm still getting the same issue. The code is very simple so I'm now at a loss for what could be the issue, I know it's possible because I've got it working (somehow) in another app. Here's the code from the sample app:

```swift
AppDelegate.swift

import CocoaLumberjack

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance)
        let fileLogger = DDFileLogger()
        fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24
        fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
        DDLog.add(fileLogger)
        DDLogInfo("Did finish launching")
        return true
    }


}
```

```swift
ViewController.swift

import CocoaLumberjack

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DDLogInfo("View did load")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        guard let fileLogger = DDLog.allLoggers.compactMap({ $0 as? DDFileLogger }).first else { fatalError() }
        let logURLs = fileLogger.logFileManager.sortedLogFilePaths.map { URL(fileURLWithPath: $0) }
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [logURLs], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }


}
```

I've tripled checked that the logs exist on disk, both on device and on the simulator and they do. If I inspect the URLs in the `logURLs` constant I can navigate to the logs on disk and even open them in Console just fine like any other logs.

Answer (score 1):

I properly figured it out after taking a break and looking at the previous answer I posted. The reason it wasn't working is because I was passing an array of URLs inside of another array when creating the `UIActivityViewController`.

So this line: `UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [logURLs], applicationActivities: nil)`

Should be: `UIActivityViewController(activityItems: logURLs, applicationActivities: nil)`